# Eclipse installing new software

Tags: java, eclipse, wso2

Eclipse Luna doesn't allow me to install any new plugin. I am having following error while trying to add software.

```
Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wso2-developer-studio. 
Unable to read repository at ....location.
```

I took the necessary steps like checking network connections, addding -vmarg- argument in .ini files. But no avail.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Please format your error message properly (and it would be probably better to post its full text).

Comment: Since you seem to be relatively new to SO this may not be that obvious or that visible so maybe you need to know that to update your question you need to use [edit] option.

Comment: @Pshemo - true, but other users with sufficient reputation can also edit.

Comment: @AdityaRamkumar yes, but to do this properly they would have to know original formatting and preferably full error message (also it would be good to let OP learn a little about editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to install [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) in Eclipse Luna. WSO2 Developer Studio latest release (3.7.1) is supported in Eclipse Kepler (not in Luna yet). If you have troubles in installing WSO2 Developer Studio in your Eclipse, you can simply download the complete installation pack (Eclipse Kepler + WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7.1) from [their site](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) as mentioned in [their doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Installation#Installation-Completeinstallation).

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks for this specific info.

Comment: If so, please accept the answer so that others can benefit from it

Comment: I am facing an issue while running enterprise service bus and WSO2 server at the same time. While trying to login to console panel of ESB, I end up with server interface. Do you have any opinion on this?

Comment: what do you mean by "WSO2 server"? which product?

Comment: I deployed my service on WSO2 application server . This is a WSO2 product and I want to invoke the service at WSO2 enterprise service bus. Hence,I have to have both running at the same time.

Comment: if you are installing multiple wso2 products on the same machine, then you need to change their default ports to avoid port conflicts. Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset

Answer (score 0):

> Start Eclipse with -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>
> Go to Window -> Preferences -> Install/update: Available Software sites. Then remove and add the luna site. Just remember to copy the adress so you can add it again. or select the entry ond reloa it.

Comment: I tried this already and I mentioned in my question. Still thanks for your feedback.